# Regex pattern that contains a limited set of special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

The requirements I've been set are...

MUST match (1 minimum character/number):

- 1 number `(?=.*\d)`
- 1 lower case character `(?=.*[a-z])`
- 1 upper case character `(?=.*[A-Z])`
- no whitespace `(?!.*\s)`
- Between 8 and 40 characters `.{8,40}`

CAN match, but doesn't have to:

- Special characters limited to `$*%!.,^`

**This is what I have so far:** `/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{8,40}/`

I'd like to keep it segmented out the way I do for readability - Unless there's a reason not to?!  Happy to change if there are any performance benefits, or if I've done something silly/pointless?

The above works for the most part, including my special characters.  However, when I type in a "restricted" character, such as `@`, it still matches.

I'm a bit lost, so any help would be very much appreciated!  Thank you!

**Examples of what SHOULD match:**

- abcABC123
- aaBB33!!
- !a*Bc9!.abBC*4

**Examples of what SHOULD NOT match:**

- abc ABC 123
- abc@ABC?123
- áááBBB333

**Restrictions:**

Anything that is NOT `a-z A-Z 0-9 or $*%!.,^` is considered a restricted character

Comment: Do you have some examples of strings that should match the pattern, or are these requirements all we're working with?

Comment: What are you defining as "restricted characters"? Your `.{8,40}` doesn't set any restrictions nor do any of your look-aheads...

Comment: dot '.' matches any character other than \n. That is why you are matching so many things.

Comment: So for example `abcABC123` would match, as would `abcABC123!!!` but something that doesn't contain any of the characters listed above wouldn't, so for example `abcABC123@@@`

Comment: @Christian I've updated the post with a few examples

Comment: @dvo I've updated my post with a couple of examples.  My definition of restricted character is anything that's NOT a-z A-Z 0-9 or $*%!.,^

Comment: Never understood why you would want to limit the character set used for passwords. When you restrict it, aren't you restricting entropy and underlying security?

Comment: @PJProudhon Per the opening sentence "The requirements I've been set are..." I would guess that this is a blind coding assignment whose sole purpose is to get OP to learn regex.

Comment: @anubhava per "Special characters limited to `$*%!.,^`" I would assume not

Comment: This is always the same: `^`, then lookaheads, then comes the consuming pattern where you define what is allowed and what is not, then `$`. If you use `.` in the consuming part you allow anything but line breaks. Just use a character class, as is shown in many already posted answers.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I guess so. But I find these times appropriate to fight against these long lasting nonsense limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z\d$*%!.,^]{8,40}$
```

- `^(?=\D*\d)` - require a digit somewhere
- `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])` - require a lowercase char somewhere
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` - require a uppercase char somewhere
- `[a-zA-Z\d$*%!.,^]{8,40}$` - from start to finish require 8 to 40 of these whitelisted chars in any order

Test your strings one at a time at https://regex101.com/r/lrABwJ/1

Comment: `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z\d$*%!.,^]{8,40}$` is lot more efficient than `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])^[a-zA-Z\d$*%!.,^]{8,40}$`

Comment: @anubhava Actually, there is no difference if you test a string once with `RegExp#test`. The multiline test at regex101.com with `g` modifier just tricks you up.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Exactly what I wanted!  

Out of interest - You've removed the check I had for spaces, but it still works...  What did I have wrong in my previous regex that was matching a space?!

Comment: @Nick The space requirement just sounds like a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) to trip you up. I simply omitted the whitespace from my allowed chars list `[a-zA-Z\d$*%!.,^]`

Comment: This all makes a lot more sense than it did 20 minutes ago!  Really appreciate your time here!  Thank you!

Comment: @Nick I saw you put forth a good-faith effort so I'm happy to help you make sense of it :-)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: https://regex101.com/r/gAREfT/3 with `g` and `m` turned off.

Comment: @anubhava Nice catch, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'd never use a password regex with `.*` in the lookahead anyway. This is bad practice. One should use the principle of contrast in this case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What would be an appropriate alternative? `.*?` seems marginally better. I am not familiar with "principle of contrast"

Comment: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, I always appreciate your insight and the performance gain is impressive. Answer updated. I just really wish the "contrast" of that site was better, *ba-dum-tss*

Comment: @Nick See my update for a more performant regex